# How to create a between date with my check in and check out

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a reserve room form. How can I create a between date with my "checkin" and "checkout", that don't allow to send the reservation ticket if already has the specific room reserved between the dates.

Only made it deny if "checkin" or "chekout" is the same day from other confirmed reservation.

```
$from = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $checkin)->format('Y-m-d');
$to = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $checkout)->format('Y-m-d');

$marcacaocounter1 = Marcacao::where('active', 1)
->whereBetween('checkin', [$from, $to])->count();

$marcacaocounter2 = Marcacao::where('active', 1)
->whereBetween('checkout', [$from, $to])->count();

if($marcacaocounter1 > 0 || $marcacaocounter2 > 0){
    $errors = true;

    return response()->json([
        'errors' => $errors,
        'errors_msg' => $errors_msg,
        'success' => $success,
        'success_msg' => $success_msg,
        'data' => $dadosJson]
    );

}
```

Comment: Please accept the modification, or edit it yourself, for a better understanding of the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Might be easiest to just pull the rooms booked between the two dates by seeing what's in the database for those rooms during that time period.  Old fashioned `where` statements with `<=` and `>=`.  Something like this (tweak to fit your needs):

```
$booked = Marcacao::where('active', 1)
   ->where('checkin', "<=", $from)
   ->where('checkout', ">=" $to)
   ->orWhere(function ($query) {
       $query->where('checkin', '>', $from)
             ->where('checkout', '<=', $to);
   })->orWhere(function ($query) {
       $query->where('checkin', '<=', $from)
             ->where('checkout', '>', $to);
   })->count()
```

Then continue with your code:

```
if($booked){
    $errors = true;

    return [...]
}
```

Comment: I guess you might not want to use `<=` because people may be able to check out and then somebody else check in on the same day.

Comment: Could be.  Or they might have fumigation and maid service for 2 days after ;)  Hope the code works for him, then he can tweak depending on how the hotel sets up.  Good point though for him to consider!

Comment: That's a good point. But if someone reserved from day 17 to 21. The next person that tries to reseve is able to reserve from 16 to 22... Can you help me out?

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit of a logic puzzle.  I've added a bit more, but you don't necessarily want to over-think this by trying to stuff it all into the perfect query which needs nested ANDs in the middle of the ORs.  Try the above.  It should get you most of the way there, if not totally.  You'll have to tweak to suit exactly what you need.  You might want to split into two if-checks if this doesn't get you all you want.  One to see if booked ON the dates, and another to check if booked to either side.  That might make the code easier to read / simplify.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like that what you are trying to do?
But, I apologize and please, if you are so kind, I could clarify the question a bit more in order to help you better.

```
$dateCheckin = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $checkin)->format('Y-m-d');
$dateCheckout = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $checkout)->format('Y-m-d');

$marcacao = Marcacao::where('active', 1)
            ->where(function($query) use ($dateCheckin, $dateCheckout){
                  $query->where([
                      ['checkin', '<=', $dateCheckin],
                      ['checkout', '>=', $dateCheckin]
                  ])
                  ->orWhere([
                      ['checkin', '<', $dateCheckout],
                      ['checkout', '>=', $dateCheckout]
                  ])
                  ->orWhere([
                      ['checkin', '>=', $dateCheckin],
                      ['checkout', '<', $dateCheckout]
                  ])
              })
            ->orderBy('checkin')
            ->get();

if(!$marcacao->isEmpty()){
    $errors = true;

    return response()->json([
        'errors' => $errors,
        'errors_msg' => $errors_msg,
        'success' => $success,
        'success_msg' => $success_msg,
        'data' => $dadosJson]
    );

}
```

And also, please, if your answer is useful, accept it and have a positive vote.

Thank you.

A cordial greeting.

Comment: But if someone reserved from day 17 to 21. The next person that tries to reseve is able to reserve from 16 to 22... Can you help me out?

Comment: @DiogoMorais, I have updated the query, with this I should get the desired result.